# Exposes implementation information to the caller?

Tags: java, generics

Within [JLS Capture Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) it discusses two ways to write the signature of the `reverse` method:

1. `public static void reverse(List<?> list);`
2. `public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list);`

   My question is **why** the second *exposes implementation information to the caller*? Specifically within the example it says that the second is   undesirable, as it exposes implementation information to the caller.

Comment: I think they mean the developers will know that `reverse` is actually implemented via `rev`, there must be a better answer anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

List<?> will return elements of type Object when iterating through the lyst. (eg: lyst.get(..) )

List<T> will return elements of Type T.

This helps to hide unneeded information to those implementing / using the interfaces.